# In media package VOD, createAsset() by using aws-sdk it gives internal server error By javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, assets, video-on-demand

I am creating assets by using aws-sdk by using createAsset() in mediaPackageVod, it gives Internal Server Error as i'm providing all the param to the function

```js
const mediapackagevod = new AWS.MediaPackageVod();
let assetParams = {
    Id: Date.now().toString(),
    PackagingGroupId: '1577XXXXXX', 
    SourceArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXX', 
    SourceRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:role/XXXXXXXX', 
    ResourceId: Date.now().toString()
};

mediapackagevod.createAsset(assetParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));           // successful response
});
```

As i already given credential and region in config.json file and the PackagingGroupId: is the Id of packaging group, SourceArn and SourceRoleArn are valid arns.
i can create asset by using aws MediaPackageVod console that is by using GUI of the aws web site

Comment: I found the solution

Comment: Please share the solution as answer. I'm facing the same issue